# Spring security not displaying the default login page for my restricted url

Tags: security, spring-security, spring-session

I have created a spring security application with h2 db,what my requirement is that when any user tries to login to a particular url "api/v1*/,it should be authenticated with the spring default login page.

Also i need to bypass the h2 console,so i have provided the following configuration for spring security.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

But with the above config,url pattern "api/v1*/ is not authenticated and it get access to the content of this url without prior auth.But if i remove this config,i am able to see the login page for the restricted url,but again the h2 db console access will be revoked.

Is there any thing wrong in my configuration?

Comment: This is surprising. It should actually work as is. By removing config do you mean commenting out the line `.antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()`?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I mean by commenting out the configure method.

Comment: Please make one more experiment and comment out the one line only. See if everything is authenticated then.